# Android download binary files from firebase - Google Play Policy

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Sometimes is hard to contact Google Play support and taking a really cleared answer about some special cases. So my question is if is it allowed to download executable binaries from Google Firebase after ask the user before that.

Some binaries are very larger like : nmap for Android, and it's better to upload to Firebase Storage and if a user want to use Nmap simply ask for start downloading for this binary...

But Google Policy says :

> We don’t allow apps that steal data, secretly monitor or harm users,
>   or are otherwise malicious.
>
> An app distributed via Google Play may not modify, replace, or update
>   itself using any method other than Google Play’s update mechanism.
>   Likewise, an app may not download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so
>   files) from a source other than Google Play. This restriction does not
>   apply to code that runs in a virtual machine and has limited access to
>   Android APIs (such as JavaScript in a webview or browser).
>
> The following are explicitly prohibited:
>
> Viruses, trojan horses, malware, spyware or any other malicious
>   software.
>
> Apps that link to or facilitate the distribution or installation of
>   malicious software.
>
> Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or
>   native code, from a source other than Google Play.
>
> Apps that introduce or exploit security vulnerabilities.
>
> Apps that steal a user’s authentication information (such as usernames
>   or passwords) or that mimic other apps or websites to trick users into
>   disclosing personal or authentication information.
>
> Apps may not depict unverified or real world phone numbers, contacts,
>   addresses, or personally identifiable information of non-consenting
>   individuals or entities.
>
> Apps that install other apps on a device without the user’s prior
>   consent.
>
> Apps designed to secretly collect device usage, such as commercial
>   spyware apps.

So this is what google says , and the cute part is :

> We don't allow Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex
>   files or native code, from a source other than Google Play.

**Is Firebase Storage considered like Google Play source ?
How do you think, can we implement or not this feature to the app ? Or maybe is there any other way to do that without publishing the apk with those binarie included**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the terms and conditions of an app distribution channel, not programming. Questions about app distribution channels [are considered to be off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare, maybe not about programing, but it is a question about what me and other programmer can do if they want to implement some code to do that...

Comment: @EAKTEAM That doesn't matter.  We aren't lawyers, and we aren't the 3rd party.  Only they can tell you what they want, or what a user agreement means.  We can't.  All questions about TOS or user agreements are off topic here (except stack exchange's own, which may be on topic in meta)

Comment: @GabeSechan, understand clearly, you are right, just i wanted a thought... Will delete it now

Comment: @GabeSechan I can't delete it, maybe someone "moderator" or something like this maybe can it says that can't be deleted because others have answered, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage is not Google Play.  You would be violating the terms if you downloaded and execute from there.

The reason why Google Play doesn't want you to download executables from other places is because Google doesn't want viruses or other malware to be distributed via Android apps.  Google Play scans everything uploaded to the console for malware, so if you bypass that, they can no longer protect the end user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , this is exactly what the weird thing is. So it means that Google Firebase Storage doesn't scan files for viruses or other malware ? Anyway, any idea how to solve this without publishing the apk with those binaries included or it is not allowed ?

Comment: Cloud Storage doesn't scan for malware.

Comment: So if i implement this, to download binaries from firebase and to execute they from app will they catch this :) :) ?? Or it is better not to risk...
Maybe something can be done with expansion files ? But i didn't find any documentation for that...

Comment: I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Can we use `expansion files` for that ? i didn't find any good documentation for those cases

Comment: Stock Overflow is not for extended lines of questioning.  Please research on your own, and ask a different question if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry about extended lines